# Error in if (nchar(current) > nchars) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm encountering an issue with an R dataframe that I read from csv using tidyverse read.csv() function. When I try to view values of a variable by typing `df$varname`, a popup window interrupts me while I'm typing the variable name. The window, and the console, say the same error message in the title of this post.

I can still finish typing the variable name and run the code to view values in the df, but this popup window error message is annoying. It stops me from selecting the variable name of interest from the dropdown menu that pops up when I write `df$` and forces me to type the full variable name.

This error does not happen when I create a dataframe manually in R, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("apple", "banana", "orange"),
  C = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
)
```

I'm using RStudio 2023.03.1 build 446 on Windows 11 and R 4.2.2

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, what version? It sounds like an RStudio editor problem rather than an R problem. And what version of R are you running?

Comment: Issue seems to be when your dataframe contains a POSIX date column. I fixed using this advice: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12918#issuecomment-1512256898